# Understanding Azimuth

Tags: operating-system, urbit

I want to understand how the Azimuth works and how is identity created and then stored on Ethereum. Basically how all of this process work?

Also, where is azimuth connected to urbit? If I have to make some changes or say remove azimuth and attach a different identity mechanism, how to do that?

I got to know that Urbit creates a unique identity and then Azimuth takes that identity and stores it on Ethereum.